# Why is the program adding extra 0's to the end of the numbers?

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a timer that displays the time left as H:M:S. The problem that I am having is that when the seconds value gets to be below 10 it prints with an exrta 0 at the end. For example, it would look like...10, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 00.
How can I make it so that it prints correctly without the extra 0?

Also, I was wondering if it was possible to print a 0 in front of the time value if there was only 1 digit in it. For example, 09, 08...

This is my code...

```
# goal is to have a timer that prints time as 00:00:00 (H:M:S)
import time

hours = int(input("Hours: "))
minutes = int(input("Minutes: "))
seconds = int(input("Seconds: "))

t = (3600 * hours) + (60 * minutes) + seconds

print('\r', hours, ':', minutes, ':', seconds, end='')

while t > 0:
    if seconds == 0 and t > 0 and minutes > 0:
        minutes -= 1
        seconds = 60

    if minutes == 0 and t > 0 and hours > 0:
        hours -= 1
        minutes = 59

    time.sleep(1)
    seconds -= 1
    t -= 1
    print('\r', hours, ':', minutes, ':', seconds, end='')

print()
print()
print("TIME DONE")
```

Comment: Look at what `'%02d:%02d:%02d' % (hours, minutes, seconds)` evaluates to.

Comment: BTW, would I be correct to assume you're _intentionally_ reimplementing logic that Python has standard-library code to do itself (in the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) and [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#module-time) modules) for the experience / sake of an exercise?

Comment: That would be correct, I had never used the time module before and thought that this would be a good way to get practice without just using what is already built in. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @Joshua and if you solved it, please mark one of the answers accepted.or you can post your answer,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) like this:

```
# goal is to have a timer that prints time as 00:00:00 (H:M:S)
import time

hours = int(input("Hours: "))
minutes = int(input("Minutes: "))
seconds = int(input("Seconds: "))

t = (3600 * hours) + (60 * minutes) + seconds

print('\r', str(hours).zfill(2), ':',str(minutes).zfill(2), ':', str(seconds).zfill(2), end='') # here

while t > 0:
    if seconds == 0 and t > 0 and minutes > 0:
        minutes -= 1
        seconds = 60

    if minutes == 0 and t > 0 and hours > 0:
        hours -= 1
        minutes = 59

    time.sleep(1)
    seconds -= 1
    t -= 1
    print('\r', str(hours).zfill(2), ':', str(minutes).zfill(2), ':', str(seconds).zfill(2), end='') # here

print()
print()
print("TIME DONE")
```

Or you can do this(with string format):

```
# goal is to have a timer that prints time as 00:00:00 (H:M:S)
import time

hours = int(input("Hours: "))
minutes = int(input("Minutes: "))
seconds = int(input("Seconds: "))

t = (3600 * hours) + (60 * minutes) + seconds
print('%02d:%02d:%02d' % (hours, minutes, seconds))

while t > 0:
    if seconds == 0 and t > 0 and minutes > 0:
        minutes -= 1
        seconds = 60

    if minutes == 0 and t > 0 and hours > 0:
        hours -= 1
        minutes = 59

    time.sleep(1)
    seconds -= 1
    t -= 1
    print('%02d:%02d:%02d' % (hours, minutes, seconds))

print()
print()
print("TIME DONE")
```